# Wrong Answer while doing concatenation in an ashx page

Tags: ashx

```
string name = id + '_' + pos + '_' + nextid;
```

This is my code in an .ashx page. My expected result is name=1_12_2 and i am getting it as name=2062.

Comment: There's too little code here for us to diagnose the issue. Don't just add more code to the question though - please try to create a [mcve].

Comment: Do you get 2032 or 2062? I'm asking because the former is what you would expect to get if you declared id and pos as integers but nextid as a string.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I got that answer. I changed my code like this         string name = id + "_" + pos + "_" + nextid;